# Minifiy SASS using Gulp, PostCSS and PurgeCSS

Tags: css, sass, gulp, postcss

despite my sass gulptask, my `.min.css` file is still `148kb` tall ... Does anyone have an idea what else I can change about my task to shrink my .min.css even more? Does any of you use other packages that offer even better compression?

```js
gulp.task('sass', done => {
    gulp.src(src + 'assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['node_modules']
        }))
        .pipe(postcss(
            [
                tailwindcss(src + 'tailwind.config.js'),
                cssnano({
                    preset: 'default',
                }),
                purgecss({
                    content: [src + '/**/*.html'],
                    extractors: [{
                        extractor: TailwindExtractor,
                        extensions: ['html']
                    }]
                }),
                autoprefixer(),
            ],
        ))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + 'assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    done();
});
```

Comment: How big is the file without compression?

Comment: @TheDancingCode 440KB...

Answer (score 0):

I heard Adam Wathan and Jeffrey Way talking about [Brotli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli) on the Full Stack Radio podcast. It seemed to compress Tailwind CSS to considerably small amounts. TBH, I have never used it myself.

Check it out here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli